# Hide existing Silverlight control in Lightswitch screen

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch

In Lightswitch is possible to create custom properties for each screen, then if you drag and drop this property to designer there are automatically created controls, my problem is that I use this property - controls for generic data and I use only part of them (in dependency to some selected entity in some collection) so I want to hide controls which I don't want to display for current entity, but not only hide like to make it invisible but also get reserved space, i tried following codes

```
      this.FindControl("MyControl").IsVisible = false;
```

But this one only makes it invisible, but it still reserves the space.

```
  this.FindControl("MyControl").ControlAvailable += (e, g) => {
    TextBox textBox = (g.Control as TextBox);
    textBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
  };
```

This also only make it invisible, but it still reserves the space. Even when this enum comment looks like this:

> Do not display the element and do not reserve space for it in the layout.

So how can I hide control and get reserved space of it in Lightswitch?